# Communication between OnMessageSend event and the add-in (Outlook)

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

The case concerns the Outlook add-in, namely the communication between the OnMessageSend event and the add-in.

Short description:
The user is authorized in an external service. After logging in, he receives a 'Token' that is used in communication between the add-in and the external service. The token is stored in the cookies.

Add-in is designed for Windows platform.
The use of the OnMessageSend event is described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/smart-alerts-onmessagesend-walkthrough)

It looks like the OnMessageSend event handling is performed regardless of the environment in which the add-in is running. So I can't read the cookies that my add-on has saved (communication via localStorage also doesn't work). Unless I am wrong and it is otherwise.

Problem:
My problem is that in the handling of the OnMessageSend event I have to do a POST to an external service, to do this I need a 'Token' that has been saved in cookies by an add-in.

**Is there a way to communicate between the add-in and the OnMessageSend event handler?

How can I pass a 'Token' from the add-in to the OnMessageSend event handler?**

Thank you in advance for any hints

Comment: Can you please explain the flow a bit more? 
1. Which outlook client are you using (OWA / Win32 / Outlook for Mac )
2. How are you storing tokens in the first place? Is it via some task pane or display dialog-based add-in? 
3. What do you mean by this "OnMessageSend event handling is performed regardless of the environment " ?

Comment: 1. Microsoft® Outlook® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2209 Build 16.0.15629.20152) 32-bit 
2. The token is stored in the cookies. (log in is via a dialog-based add-in)
3. e.g. add-in loads jQuery library and in the OnMessageSend event handler I can't use jQuery loaded in add-in.

Comment: There isn't a way to communicate between cookies and the JS in the OnMessageSend LaunchEvent. However, if you are getting the data while you are using displayDialogAsync. The dialog should be able to communicate back to the parent executeFunction (or showTaskpane) the token in the cookie. And then use the Session Data API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.sessiondata?view=outlook-js-preview to save the token in session data. The SessionData should be retrievable by the OnMessageSend JS

Answer (score 1):

It is working for me. Use Office.context.mailbox.item.sessionData.setAsync in your Taskpane JS and then fetch using Office.context.mailbox.item.sessionData.getAsync in your launchevent.js

```
let oData = JSON.stringify(objData);
//console.log(oData);
Office.context.mailbox.item.sessionData.setAsync("bookingObject", oData, function (asyncResult) {
    if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
        //console.log("sessionData.setAsync succeeded");
    }
    else {
        console.log("Failed to set sessionData. Error: " + JSON.stringify(asyncResult.error));
    }
});
```

```html
Office.context.mailbox.item.sessionData.getAsync("bookingObject", function (asyncResultBO) {
                    if (asyncResultBO.status !== Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
                        console.error(`BO Error:: ${asyncResultBO.error.message}`);
                        event.completed();
                        return;
                    }
                    const bookingObjectAllData = JSON.parse(asyncResultBO.value);
                    $.each(bookingObjectAllData["Office365AddInBookingItem"], function (index, item) { if (item.IsAddon == false) { ResourceIds = ResourceIds + item.ResourceId + ","; } });
                    originalAppointment.ResourceIds = ResourceIds;


                    result = checkRoomAvailabilityOutlook(originalAppointment.ResourceIds, originalAppointment.start, originalAppointment.end);
```

Comment: Outlook 365 failed to send POST request. Does it work for you?